# How to cover screw holes on a plywood floor

Tags: flooring, woodworking, hardwood-floor, routers

This is the floor in a space where every 1/16" of vertical space counts, so we decided to use the plywood covering the joists as the floor. It looks OK, but the seams and the screw holes are quite unsightly. Any recommendations on improving the situation?

I was considering routing out strips 1.5" wide and 1/32" deep, then gluing in a 1/16" strip of pine and sanding it down. But I'm not sure how to straighten out the rounded edge at the end of each groove, how to make sure that the glue holds without fasteners, etc.

I've learned that epoxy does not stick to wood, but is there some epoxy-based solution?

[image]

Comment: There are certainly epoxies that stick to wood.  I'm getting absolutely fed up with the number of epoxy-and-wood projects appearing in woodworking magazines recently....

Comment: "quite unsightly. Any recommendations on improving the situation?" makes this a decorating question which is off-topic. What, exactly, is your "decorating" goal, and we can help you achieve that, but we don't suggest decorating ideas.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a sledgehammer to crack a nut. All the screw heads should be countersunk (can't tell), just under the surface, and any filler, polyester two pack, etc., used to bring back the level to that of the ply. If it's looks you're after, please specify in the question. Why mention hardwood floor?

Answer (score 2):

There is a reason they use hard wood for floors, plywood is a soft wood and it will not last. The best solution is to go as designed and cover with an appropriate flooring material. That will be much faster and a lot less work for you. Your labor/time is worth something. From the photo it appears ready for a flooring to be applied, holes are filled, sanded etc.

Answer (score 2):

You are planning on using material that is not intended as a finished surface, as a finished surface. There are no magic cures. Unless you accept the fact that there needs to be some other flooring over the plywood you will always be left with a uncomely looking floor.
A very good quality LVP or LVT floor is only about 5.5mm...that's less than 1/4 inch. It is hard to believe that thickness in flooring would make the room unusable.

Answer (score 1):

You can straighten out the rounded edges with a sharp wood chisel. You want to get some waterproof wood glue and coat both surfaces and join th two surfaces together. Weigh them down with some bricks or other weights. Clean off any glue that oozes out quickly.

The glueing will be the easyy part compared to the routing ou plan on doing.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the screws are already filled with something. **You'll need to remove that enough to access the screw heads and maybe drive them deep enough so that you can route out a channel for the cover piece.** Hitting a screw head with a router bit has the potential to be catastrophic. Think: *shattering router bit   pieces flying off at phenomenal speeds in random directions*) so if you're planning on routing out a 1/32" deep channel you'd want to sure that the screw heads are sunk well past that depth.

Once you have the screw heads out of your way you'll need to improvise a straight-edge guide to route out the actual channels. Perhaps nailing a pair of 1x4s across the seams would be enough. In that case, you're going to have to be careful to maintain a consistent placement and parallelism of the guides as you move across the floor.

**Use a sharp chisel to cut back the rounded corners at the end of the routed channels.** You'll end up with a section of floor where the router can't reach equal to the width of the router base to the cutting edge of the bit (maybe 2-3") that will have to be cut with a chisel too.

Once you have the channels routed out, you can use a water-proof wood glue to glue down the strips. You can either weight the strips down or use scraps of wood and a pin nailer to keep everything in place while the glue dries.

Then, instead of sanding the excess filler strip down to the floor surface, you might consider setting the router to the height of the floor and cutting off the top of the filler strips flush (or very slightly proud) of the floor surface. If you leave them slightly proud, you'll finish it off with sanding. That should be a lot quicker and easier than trying to sand off the 1/32" that's left proud otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

A: Epoxy sticks to wood just fine, so be careful where you "learn things."

B: Floor paint. Won't take up more than a few thousands of an inch, even if you use 3 coats. Doesn't need to be epoxy, but can be. However, non-epoxy will be thinner, on average. Epoxy will do a better job of leveling any imperfectly filled divots, though. Make it a nice opaque solid color and kiss the unsightly joints and screws goodbye.